# Snake_Case to PascalCase with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I Have a C# project where the class properties are all in `Snake_Case`, I want to convert them to `PascalCase` as recommended by [Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

also, the parameter names are in `snake_Case` and I'm using angular on the frontend and during deserialization, these properties are converted to snake_Case I want to convert `snake_Case` to `pascalCase`

I'm using VS code so I wanna use the search and replace functionality

e.g

```
Snake_Case --> SnakeCase

snake_Case --> snakeCase
```

i have tried:

```
([a-z])_([A-Z])
$1$2
```

but that does not work on `GG_Registration_Number` is becomes `GG_RegistraionNumber`

Comment: Use `(\p{L})_(\p{Lu})` instead of `([a-z])_([A-Z])`

Answer (score 0):

`G` is in upper case, `([a-z])` only captures lower case.

Use

```
([a-zA-Z])_([A-Z])
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```